# mysql select convert to zend framework select

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, select, selectlist

I'trying to convert a simple mysql select querys to zend framework select

so  I've this:

```
<?php
 $HOST = "localhost";
 $USER = "root";
 $PASS = "";

$conexion = mysql_connect($HOST,$USER,$PASS) or die("Problemas en la conexion");
 mysql_select_db("rapidoypoderosodb",$conexion) or die("Problemas en la seleccion de la base de  datos");
 mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");


$sql= "SELECT DISTINCT  * FROM especialistas WHERE activo='1'order by estado";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$options = '<option id="idSelect" value="">seleccione estado...</option>';

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    $estado = $row["estado"];
    $options.='<OPTION VALUE="'.$estado.'">'.$estado.'</option>';
}
echo $options;
?>
```

and I've converted:

```
<?php
    global $WHG_DB_HOST, $WHG_DB_USER,$WHG_DB_PASSWD,$WHG_DB_REPLDB;
            $db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
                'host' => $WHG_DB_HOST,
                'username' => $WHG_DB_USER,
                'password' => $WHG_DB_PASSWD,
                'dbname'   => $WHG_DB_REPLDB
            ));
            $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
        $select = $db->select() 
                        ->distinct()
                        ->from(array('e' => 'especialistas'))  
                        ->where('e.activo = 1', $VARIABLE)
                        ->order('e.estado');            

        $result = $db->fetchAll($select);
        $options = '<option id="idSelect" value="">seleccione estado...</option>';                      
        foreach($result as $row){
            $estado = $row["estado"];
            $options.='<OPTION VALUE="'.$estado.'">'.$estado.'</option>';
        }
        echo $options;
?>
```

the problem is that doesn't work theory my index.php give me a list to choise one option and doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most easiest way to debug `Select` is to manually try generated SQL query. Just echo your select instance, `__toString` method will assemble query.

Regarding your code, only one small mistake there in where clause. Define values as second parameter so it's correctly escaped and quoted.

```
    $select = $db->select()
        ->distinct()
        ->from(['e' => 'especialistas'])
        ->where('e.activo = ?', 1)
        ->order('e.estado');
```